Finding the turning point of $f(x)=\ln(xe^x+ 1)-x^4$
I am a calculus student and this question is part of my homework assignment. I have to find the turning point in the interval $x\in[0,2]$ of the following function.
The function we were given is $f(x)=\ln(xe^x + 1)-x^4$
It is easy to differentiate the function to get $f'(x)=-4x^3 + \frac{e^x(1+x)}{1+xe^x}$.
Though I cannot find a way to solve for the values of $x$ of the derivative. I have tried everything I know, so anything is appreciated.

The turning point is where the function goes from increasing to decreasing (or vice-versa); i.e. where the derivative vanishes. In your case, it appears $f'(x)=0$ cannot be solved for $x$ in closed form using elementary functions, so I would assume your teacher meant for you to solve this approximately using numerical or graphical methods.

What is turning point? Isn't it a second derivative thing?

I will try to help you with your question. As Raad was suggesting in the comments, the turning point cannot be found in closed form using elementary functions, but it can only be estimated numerically. What you can do analytically, without using special functions and other fancy stuff, is admit its existence.
In the following I will try to prove that such turning point exists, and I will do that combining Bolzano's Theorem and Rolle's Theorem.
Bolzano's Theorem states that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[x,y]$ and $f(x)$ has opposite sign with respect to $f(y)$ ($f(x)f(y)<0$), then there must exist a root $\alpha$ in the open interval $(x,y)$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$.
If we consider the closed interval $[0,2]$, then we know $f$ to be both continuous and differentiable on it. Then, if we compute both $f(0)$ and $f(2)$, we get that: $$f(0) = 0, f(2) = ln(2e^2 + 1) - 16 \approx -14.8 < 0$$ Now, since $f(0)=0$, we cannot still apply Bolzano's Theorem: we need to consider another inner point of $(x,y)$ and reiterate the process. Said inner point could be the midpoint of the interval $[0,2]$, which is $z=(0+2)/2=1$: $$f(1) = ln(e+1)-1 \approx 0.31>0$$ We are now able to apply Bolzano's Theorem to the interval $[1,2]$, implying there exists $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. At this point what you can do is reiterate Newton's Bisection Method $k$ times until you are satisfied with the value of $\alpha$. Then, you can apply Rolle's Theorem in the interval $[0,\alpha]$. Through the latter you can state that there exists a turning point $c$ within $(0,\alpha)$, since $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\alpha]$, differentiable on $(0,\alpha)$ and $f(0)=f(\alpha)=0$.

When graphed, the actual solution is 0.708, which is very nearly ln(2). You can use $x = ln(2)$ with Newton’s Method to quickly iterate into the actual solution.
Also, although it does not give exactly the solution, the following method is still close despite using only elementary functions.
If you rearrange the terms and multiply by x, you get this equation:
$$\frac{xe^x}{1 + xe^x} = \frac{4x^4}{1 + x}$$
And so it would be convenient if:
$$x = xe^x = 4x^4$$
But, $xe^x$ does not equal $x$ except at zero. However, $4x^4$ can equal either of them, but at different points, and on a graph, we see the actual solution is lying somewhere between those two points, $4x^4 = x$ and $xe^x = 4x^4$.
Therefore, to construct a fascimile of $x = xe^x$ at a point other than zero, we can minimize the distance away $4x^4$ is from $x$ and from $xe^x$, by finding the the equality:
$$xe^x - 4x^4 = 4x^4 - x$$
Which reduces to a cubic polynomial, that can be solved by expanding $e^x$ into its series form $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and truncating off the later terms.
The solution of this polynomial is 0.725.
Or, since for small $x$, $4x^4$ is still sort of linear, one could select the midpoint between the points, which is 0.7305.
